# CSS Shape is not as expected. How to resolve?

Tags: html, css

In this code, I am trying to get a shape as my expectation. But I am failing to do it? Can you please tell me where I am wrong. Why my code is not working as Expected. As per knowledge all classes working properly except marker nose. Why my marker nose style is not working properly? Can you please guide me.

Expectation:

[image: CSS Shape]

```css
.hoarding_marker{
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translateX(50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
}
.hoarding_marker_content{
    font-size:  12px;
    background-color: #697379;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 4px;
    color: #fff;
    min-width: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.hoarding_marker_nose{
  height: 6px;
  width: 12px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 3px auto 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
}
.hoarding_marker_nose:before{
  margin-top: -3px;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  border: 6px solid #fff;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent;
  border-width: 6px 6px 0;
  margin-left: -6px;
  left: 50%;
}
.hoarding_marker_nose:after{
  margin-top: -4px;
  border-color: #697379 transparent transparent;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  border: 6px solid #fff;
  border-width: 6px 6px 0;
  margin-left: -6px;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="hoarding_marker" style="position: absolute; z-index: 160; transition: opacity 0.4s ease 212ms; opacity: 1;">
  <div class="hoarding_marker_content">₹2,193</div>
  <div class="hoarding_marker_nose"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the border shorthand property to to border-style: solid on the before element and increase the z-index so it's visible on top of the bubble.

```css
.hoarding_marker{
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translateX(50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
}
.hoarding_marker_content{
    font-size:  12px;
    background-color: #697379;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 4px;
    color: #fff;
    min-width: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.hoarding_marker_nose{
  height: 6px;
  width: 12px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 3px auto 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
}
.hoarding_marker_nose:before{
  margin-top: -4px;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color: #697379 transparent transparent;
  border-width: 6px 6px 0;
  margin-left: -6px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="hoarding_marker" style="position: absolute; z-index: 160; transition: opacity 0.4s ease 212ms; opacity: 1;">
  <div class="hoarding_marker_content">₹2,193</div>
  <div class="hoarding_marker_nose"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code:

```css
.hoarding_marker_content{
    font-size:  12px;
    background-color: #697379;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 4px;
    color: #fff;
    min-width: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
.hoarding_marker_content:after {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
    border-right: 8px solid transparent;
    content: '';
    border-top: 8px solid #697379;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -7px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
    <div class="hoarding_marker_content">₹2,193</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code this one is like as you expected.

```css
.hoarding_marker{
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translateX(50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
}
.hoarding_marker_content{
    font-size:  12px;
    background-color: #697379;
    border-top: 3px solid #dccfcf;
    border-right: 3px solid #dccfcf;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #dccfcf;
    border-left: 3px solid #dccfcf;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 4px;
    color: #fff;
    min-width: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.hoarding_marker_nose{
  height: 6px;
  width: 12px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 3px auto 0;
}
.hoarding_marker_nose:before{
  margin-top: -11px;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  border: 6px solid #697379;
  border-color: #697379 transparent transparent;
  border-width: 6px 6px 0;
  margin-left: -6px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.hoarding_marker_nose:after{
  margin-top: -4px;
  border-color: #697379 transparent transparent;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  border: 6px solid #fff;
  border-width: 6px 6px 0;
  margin-left: -6px;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="hoarding_marker" style="position: absolute; z-index: 160; transition: opacity 0.4s ease 212ms; opacity: 1;">
  <div class="hoarding_marker_content">₹2,193</div>
  <div class="hoarding_marker_nose"></div>
</div>
```